# SQLite get values from input array as row values

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

How to get the values row wise which are from a given array?
E.g. we have an input array (named) akshar = ["क","ख","ग","घ","च","छ","ज","झ"], then I want to get these values as rows under column name akshar in SQLite something looking like `select a from ("क","ख","ग","घ","च","छ","ज","झ") [a]`:

`akshar`

क

ख

ग

घ

च

छ

ज

झ

Explanation:  I am having an array of characters against which I have to query data from the database and need to have those characters as rows under single column (say `akshar`) so that I can join other tables and fetch other required values corresponding to those characters. So the (first) requirement is to get the values from a given array (in code) as row values of sqlite query result under single `akshar` column. I have tried the `...where in (क, ख, ग...)...` clause with sqlite array but this returns the only rows of characters which exist in the database.

Comment: I do not think we have array datatype in sqlite. Did you mean how to transform a comma de-limited string to column ?

Comment: You can't. If you're trying to dynamically select columns like this, its a sign that you need a related table with a row for each "column".

Comment: @NandalalSeth, @ColonelThirtyTwo, I am having an array of characters against which I have to query data from the database and need to have those characters as rows under single column (say `akshar`) so that I can join other tables and fetch other required values corresponding to those characters. So the (first) requirement is to get the values from a given array (in code) as row values under single `akshar` column. I have tried the `where in (क, ख, ग...)` clause with sqlite array but this returns the only rows of characters which exist in the database.

Answer (score 1):

So far I have tried and achieved the same with recursive query as below which splits the character string and returns those characters as rows:

```
with recursive varn(pratham,dwiteey) as (select  'अ', 'आ|इ|ई|उ|ऊ|ऋ|ए|ऐ|ओ|औ|क|ख|ग|घ|ङ|च|छ|ज|झ|ञ|ट|ठ|ड|ढ|ण|त|थ|द|ध|न|प|फ|ब|भ|म|य|र|ल|व|श|ष|स|ह|श्र|क्ष|त्र|ज्ञ|ा|ि|ी|ु|ू|ृ|े|ै|ो|ौ|ं|ः|ँ|्|०|१|२|३|४|५|६|७|८|९|' union all select substr(dwiteey,1,instr(dwiteey,'|')-1), ltrim(dwiteey,'|'||substr(dwiteey,1,instr(dwiteey,'|')-1)) from varn  where dwiteey!='') select pratham from varn
```

But still looking for a simpler query to achieve the same.

Comment: good attempt, and I agree with your solution in the absence of any out of the box function to do this